# Why does requiring 'watir-webdriver' in my macruby application in xcode cause this error?

Tags: ruby, xcode, watir, macruby

I have installed watir-webdriver via macgem in root and in user, I have required `rubygems` and included `/Library/Frameworks` recursively in my framework search path in build settings for this project.

require 'rubygems' runs without a problem
require 'watir-webdriver' returns the error :

```
Assertion failed: (method_getImplementation(m) == imp), function add_method, file vm.cpp, line 1019.
(lldb)
```

Im really new to using ruby in xcode can someone explain this?
Thanks

Comment: I run watir on a mac but I do not use xcode, I've installed the latest ruby 1.9.3  (I'll probably move to 2.0, but only after the rest of the project I'm testing against does that also)  (and I tend to use rubymine to as my IDE, so I'm useless with xcode..)  SO my questions.  if you run `ruby -version` from  terminal session, what does it return?   If you do `gem list` what does it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I recall hearing something about the version of ruby that ships with the mac OS being um well a kind word would be ancient  (1.8 started in 2003.. 1.8.7 in 2008, and while it has been patched more recently than that, it's still kinda old.)

Not sure what Apple's reason for not going to a 1.9 version was, but for some reason they seem to like the older stuff.

Most folks I know working on Watir use some flavor of Ruby 1.9  typically 1.9.3 or 1.9.3.    Increasingly people are shifting to 2.0, which came out in Feb.

The first thing I would try is getting a more current version or Ruby and see if that eliminates that error.   Instructions are found [here](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/)  I'm pretty sure I used RVM when I installed on my 'work' system (a macbook pro).  RVM can be pretty handy (such as if you want to experiment with 2.0) so I'd usually recommend using it for folks on a Mac